# How to find video files with a certain framewidth

Tags: windows-7, windows, video, windows-search

I have the following problem: a large collection of video files of all sorts of formats with very different framewidths and frameheights on several hard drives.

I want to **search for all video files that have a framewidth that is less than 640**, so that I can delete all those (I need to make space for 1080p videos).

In Windows 7 I do not seem to be able to do that. I see that in Windows Explorer, in the file details, if I add additional columns of info, framewidth is an option. But I do not know how to use that info in the search function of Windows 7. I had a look at the advanced search syntax, but did not see any possibilities there.

I also googled this problem, but did not immediately find any tools to do so.

If there are tools or scripts that could do this (maybe a Windows Powershell script? - unfortunately I do not know Powershell) or some other way, I would like to hear about it.

Answer (score 6):

I have been given the answer by a Microsoft person on one of their support forums:

If the videos are in one location or are included in a library on Windows Seven, one can use the windows explorer search with the keyword

> framewidth:<=640

and that gives a list of all those videos in the library.

I tried it out and it does work:

1. Start menu,
2. Type in windows search: *.mp4 framewidth:<=640

That gave me a whole list. Cool.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the best method, but you could make search queries for each the file type of your most popular video formats (e.g. "type:mpg")

Then add the column "Frame width", and sort out the search results by this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to not put a space between "frame" and "width" and be sure to follow it with a colon.  BTW 1080 is a frameheight not a framewidth.  Once you have searched, you can save the search then search the search.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.